# Is it possible to invalidate or revoke an AWS Cloudfront Signed URL after it has been created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to invalidate or revoke an AWS Cloudfront Signed URL after it has been created?

We want to be able to revoke a signed URL on-demand, not necessarily when a preset timeout happens.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible to revoke a pre-signed URL. The credentials embedded in the URL are temporary credentials linked to the credentials used to create the pre-signed URL.

The closest thing you could do is either:

- Delete or rename the object being requested by the pre-signed URL, or
- Delete the access keys used to create the pre-signed URL.

However, depending on your use-case, neither of those may be viable options.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to revoke pre-signed urls created using a role, but I am not sure if this works for your scenario.

- Create a role which has a policy with 's3:GetObject' permission. Here is how the policy would look like.

  `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
      }
  ]
  }`
- Assume this role to create a pre-signed url
- If you want to revoke the pre-signed url just delete the role and it should work.

Drawback with this approach is that if we delete the role all the pre-signed urls created using the role will not work anymore.